# assigning color codes to column values in data frame

Tags: r, colors

I have a data frame df like this

```
Pass
P01
P02
P01
P01
P02
P03
P03
P01

unique(df$Pass)
```

> ```
> "P01" "P02" "P03"
> ```

for each unique values of df$col I will generate a gradient of colours

```
cc <- scales::seq_gradient_pal("blue", "red", "Lab")(seq(0,1,length.out=length(unique(df$Pass))))
```

This will generate a vector of colours

```
cc
```

> "#0000FF" "#6D00E4" "#9300C9"

I want to assign each colours to the corresponding value and create a new column:

Output:

```
Pass col
P01  "#0000FF"
P02  "#6D00E4"
P01  "#0000FF"
P01  "#0000FF"
P02  "#6D00E4"
P03  "#9300C9"
P03  "#9300C9"
P01  "#0000FF"
```

Comment: I think `df = data.frame(Pass = Pass, col = cc)` will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new dataframe with the correspondence of colors and then join both dataframes :

```
df2=data.frame(Pass=unique(df$Pass),cc=cc)
dplyr::inner_join(df,df2)
```

Comment: yes indeed cheers